# Is this definition of a quantile proper?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, quantile

I need to find a proper definition of a quantile.
It says:
a p-th quantile $x_p$ is a number, that satisfies the following conditions:
$$
0<p<1
$$
and
$$
P(X \le x_{p}) \ge p
$$
and
$$
P(X \ge x_{p}) \ge 1-p
$$
is this definition right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, except for $0<p<1$, I would use

$$0 \leq p \leq 1$$

because probability can bei $0$ and $1$, too. The other conditions are fine.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{Yes.}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$